# Using Server-side rendering in NextJS 13 outside of the new "app" directory

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a NextJS app which I recently upgraded to NextJS 13, but it is a large system where I am not able to fully migrate it to use the new "app" directory. Now I have a component where I need to be able to use server-side rendering to fetch data but it seems that GetServerSideProps has been discontinued in NextJS 13, at least I am getting the error:
 `TS2305: Module '"next"' has no exported member 'GetServerSideProps'`

when I try to import it. I am importing like this:

```
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next'
```

Does anybody have a solution to this problem?

I have tried importing GetServerSideProps like this:

```
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next'
```

but I get this error:

`TS2305: Module '"next"' has no exported member 'GetServerSideProps'`

EDIT: I have done some research and found out that GetServerSideProps is NOT discontinued in NextJS 13 and my error is related to typescript. I have tried updating both Typescript and @types/next in my project to the most recent versions but my problem still persists.